# Git local repositories with multiple local eclipse workspaces

Tags: eclipse, git

I am starting to have a look at git before migrating from SVN.

I have read many helpfill questions here and some tutorials.

Normally, i have more than one eclipse Workspace created in my computer. Different "applications/programs" will use different eclipse workspaces.

When using git a local repo is either clone from a remote repo or created locally. The working tree of the local git repo is then refer from the eclipse workspace. This means that when i am actually changing things within eclipse i am changing them in the local git repo/ working tree.

So far is clear, but sometimes i have projects that are use in more than on application/program, thus in more than one workspace. What should in this case?

For what i have read i would thing that i would need to create a local git repo per eclipse workspace to avoid having two eclipse workspaces modifing the same local git repo/working tree which could cause all sort of trouble.

This means that, to be safe, every eclipse workspace should define a different HOME for the git repo?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create multiple workspace for the same git repo. use the

```
git worktree add <path of you worktree> <commit>
```

and modify the workspace safely.

```
git worktree --help
```

will give you detail info.